# hibernate session error

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I use hibernate for persistence. when i call the method :

```
Session s = getCurrentSession();
s.flush();
```

i geth the following message :

[toString() unavailable - no suspended threads]

and it just stops running after the s.flush() method.

I'm using JBoss IDE 1.6 and the message is shown within the Variables window when debugging.

do you have any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: where do you get that message? That's not a stack trace, where did you see it?

Comment: hi skaffman, I'm using JBoss IDE 1.6 and the message is shown within the Variables window when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the message say it all: toString() is unavailable as no thread is suspended. If you want to see the actual value in your debugging view, well, suspend a thread.